# its not printing anything

Tags: python

• Write a function strings2floats(ls) that takes a list of strings ls and returns a list of floats.
Your function should construct the list of floats to return, and not modify the list passed in.

• Write a function positive_min(lf) that returns the smallest positive float in the list lf

• Write a program min+.py that reads a list of floats from the command line and prints the smallest positive value

```
    import sys
ls=(sys.argv[1:])
def string2floats(ls):
    lf=[]
    for element in ls:
        lf.append(float(element))
    return lf
def positive_min(lf):
    minimum = float("inf")
    for i in range(0,len(lf)):
        if (minimum>lf[i] and lf[i]>0):
            minimum=lf[i]
    return minimum

positive_min(string2floats(ls))
```

Comment: We're not sure either since you don't tell us why it isn't doing what you expected

Comment: , line 5, in string2floats
    for element in range (ls):
TypeError: 'list' object cannot be interpreted as an integer

Answer (score 2):

`ls` is a list; it contains all the command-line arguments.

`range()` expects an integer; that is, the number to count up to.

If you want to iterate over a list, then just do so, you don't need range.

```
for element in ls:
```

Note, an even more Pythonic way of writing the whole `string2floats` function is as a single list comprehension:

```
lf = [float(elem) for elem in ls]
```

Comment: File "C:\Users\lollb\Desktop\Rayan\AUB\CMPS200\hometry.py", line 15, in <module>
    positive_min(string2floats(ls))
  File "C:\Users\lollb\Desktop\Rayan\AUB\CMPS200\hometry.py", line 6, in string2floats
    lf.append(float[element])
TypeError: 'type' object is not subscriptable

Comment: Yes, because `float` is a callable, not an object that you subscript with `[]`. Neither is `len`.